# How to use several input files and do parallel processing in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, parallel-processing

I have 30 csv files. I want to give it as input in for loop, in pandas?

Each file has names such as fileaa, fileab,fileac,filead,....

I have multiple input files and And i would like to receive one output.

Usually i use read_csv but due to memory error, 'read_csv' doesn't work.

```
f = "./file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="/", header=0, dtype=str)
```

So i would like to try parallel processing in python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [dask](https://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Dask docs show a [demo](https://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/dataframe-csv.html) on how to read in many csv files and output a single dask dataframe:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('*.csv')
```

And then *MANY* (but not all) of the pandas methods are available, i.e.:

```
df.head()
```

It would be useful to read more on [dask dataframe](https://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe.html) to understand difference with pandas dataframe

Comment: i get this warning :/ RuntimeWarning: Couldn't detect a suitable IP address for reaching '8.8.8.8', defaulting to '127.0.0.1': [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
  % (host, default, e), RuntimeWarning)

Comment: i get error for something that was working in pandas
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `apply`.

Original error is below:
------------------------
ValueError('could not convert string to float: foo', u'occurred at index a')

Comment: If you find dask as suitable tool to handle the task at hand then I would suggest asking a separate question addressing specific problem you are having with dask. Also note that having [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples#30424537) in your pandas/dask related question will increase the speed of getting helpful feedback.